# Dynamically reload UIViewControllers on language change

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

I am changing UITabBarItem title after the user changes his language preferences in the app settings. The problem is that the whole item disappears for a while after this change is made and then appears again with the new title.

In AppDelegate I am initializing UITabBarController:

```
self.tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
self.tabBarController.delegate = self;

BFNCategoriesTableViewController *shopViewController = [[BFNCategoriesTableViewController alloc] init];
UINavigationController *shopNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:shopViewController];
shopNavigationController.tabBarItem = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:BFNLocalizedString(kTranslationShop) image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"TabBarShopUnselected"] selectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"TabBarShopSelected"]];

self.tabBarController.viewControllers = @[offersNavigationController,
                                         shopNavigationController,
                                         //wishlistNavigationController,
                                         cartNavigationController,
                                         moreNavigationController];
```

Then after the translation is downloaded I just set different title like this:

```
navigationController.title = BFNLocalizedString(kTranslationCart);
```

Do you have an idea why this happens and eventually how to ovecome this issue?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I can't understand regarding code above, how tabBarController is connected with UINavigationController.

You should

```
self.tabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObject: shopViewController]; 
UINavigationController *shopNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController: self.tabBarController ];
```

UINavigationController doesn't have a property is tabBarItem.

Following that:

```
shopViewController.title = = BFNLocalizedString(kTranslationCart);
```

It changes a title is on top of navController and title of tabBar as well.

Another way, It can change a tabBarTitle directly.

```
UITabBar *tabBar = self.tabBarController.tabBar;
UITabBarItem *  itemBar = [ [UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:BFNLocalizedString(kTranslationCart)
                    image:(UIImage *)image // your image
            selectedImage:(UIImage *)selectedImage]; // highlighted image 
[tabBar  setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObject:itemBar
    animated:YES ];
```

I think a first way is enough it must certainly work.

Comment: I appreciate your answer. I've edited my original question to be clear how tabBarController is connected with UINavigationController. Actually UINavigationController do have a property tabBarItem and the above implementation works. The problem is that after changing the title as I've mentioned in the original post (which is the same as your first suggestions) then the tabBarItem dissappears for a a few seconds.

The other solution you've suggested doesn't work because "Directly modifying a tab bar managed by a tab bar controller is not allowed"